# Trouble in sending data to server in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

I am creating ios and android application which include chatting mechanisum.

I got problem in ios application  when I am sending message to server. Sometime message send by ios device get repeated entry in server database. It happen rearly.

I am using  ASIFormDataRequest class for communicating with server in ios.

My android app also using same API for communicating with server. Android app works properly

Code for sending message in ios is as follow.

```
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

 [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

 for (NSString* key in dictionaryWithValue) {

 [request setPostValue:[dictionaryWithValue objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

 }

 [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];

 [request setDelegate:self];

 [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];

  request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection   = NO;

  [request startSynchronous];
```

Here dictionaryWithValue is NSDictonary which contain data in key value pair.

Is there in anything getting wrong in code?

Also in ios application, image is not uploading to server. it get connection time out.

For uploading image i have used following code

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request setUploadProgressDelegate:self];
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:YES];


 [request setData:[parametersPOST objectAtIndex:2] withFileName:@"UserAvatarFile.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:KEYAvatar];

[request startSynchronous];


  NSString *fileName = [parametersPOST objectAtIndex:1];

 [request setData:[parametersPOST objectAtIndex:2] withFileName:fileName   andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:KEYAvatar];


 [request setPostValue:[parametersPOST objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"avatar"];


[request addPostValue:[parametersPOST objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"avatar"];

[request setPostValue:[parametersPOST objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"userid"];
[request setPostValue:fileName forKey:@"name"];
[request setPostValue:[parametersPOST objectAtIndex:3] forKey:@"token"];


[request startSynchronous];
```

Here parametersPOST is NSArray which contain data which i have to send to server.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSDictionary *)getParsedDictonaryforUrlString:(NSString *)urlString withData:(NSData *)postData
{    
    NSString *newURL = urlString;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newURL]                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: postData];

    // get response
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                                             error:&error];
    if (responseData == nil) 
    {
        // Check for problems
        if (responseData != nil) 
        {

        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // Data was received.. continue processing
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
        NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);

        if ([urlResponse statusCode] >=200 && [urlResponse statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", result);
            NSError *parseError = nil;
            NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:result error:parseError];     
            return xmlDictionary;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This method may help to you